# How to shoot two email (To Admin & To User who have filled the form) with SendGrid & PHP

Tags: curl, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid Api and PHP cURL in a form. My objective is to send the data to the admin of the website and send a confirmation email to user who have filled the form.

I have successfully implemented the email to Admin part, but how to shoot another email to user simultaneously? Please help.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/'; 
$user = 'xyz'; 
$pass = 'mypass'; 


$params = array(
    'api_user'  => "$user",
    'api_key'   => "$pass",
    'to'        => "email@website.com",
    'subject'   => "EM Workshop Registration",
    'html'      => "<html><head><body> message and data goes here </body></head></html>
'from'      => "admin@website.com",
  );  

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $sendgrid_apikey));
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);


header('Location: thanks.html'); 
exit();

print_r($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bcc` parameter to send the email to the user too, just modify your `$params` as

```
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => "$user",
    'api_key'   => "$pass",
    'to'        => "email@website.com",

    'subject'   => "EM Workshop Registration",
    'html'      => "<html><head><body> message and data goes here </body></head></html>
    'from'      => "admin@website.com",
    'bcc'       => "user@email.com" //JUST ADD THIS LINE
);
```

Comment: thank ayush,
but actually i want to send 2 different set of emails.

for example,

the admin would get form data and user would get a message like thank you for submitting...

Comment: You could create a php file with 2 functions, one for user and one for admin with different contents, then call those functions from the main body of your php file